# depends or depend

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

The following sentence appears in The Economist (May 30th, 2020), page 61, "More money, more problems".

I am confused by the use of **depends** rather than **depend** here. Isn't the subject here plural?

> The leveraged companies and debt instruments in PE portfolios are vulnerable and much **depends** on whether managers can tide these investments over.

Comment: "Much" is regarded as singular.  3rd person singular.

Comment: The pronoun "much" is singular, and that is the subject for the verb "depends".

Comment: 'The leveraged companies and debt instruments in PE portfolios are vulnerable and much depends on whether managers can tide these investments over.' = 'The leveraged companies and debt instruments in PE portfolios are vulnerable. A lot depends on whether managers can tide these investments over.' NOT 'The leveraged companies and debt instruments in PE portfolios are vulnerable and are greatly dependent on whether managers can tide these investments over.'